# How to export 2 database (table) columns to csv file using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have two Mysql tables that I would like to export to a csv file based on specific data found in one of the tables.

Example:

Table A-1 has Column comments.

Table A-2 has Column users.

Table A-2 has the users: John, Pam, and Joe

Table A-1 has a comment from John: I like singing.
Table A-1 has a comment from Pam: I like dancing.
Table A-1 has another comment from John: I like running.
Table A-1 has a comment from Joe: I like laughing.

How can I extract the different columns(from two different tables) information into a csv file using php?

Comment: paste the code which you tried and also the structure of both tables

Comment: I have not tried anything because I do not know where to start.  I tried reading various books, but no joy.  I am learning php and Mysql.  I have the database setup and I can see the information in the two tables.

Comment: then you need to learn basic sql so you can retrieve the data you want. when it's a simple matter of pulling up that data in php and using `fputcsv()` to write it out to your file.

Comment: If you have a couple books, then you specifically want to read about (a) SQL `SELECT` query with a `JOIN` to get your data, (b) looping in PHP to iterate through each row, and (c) the `fputcsv` function to output the data in CSV format